# WAP for Android/iPhone/WebOS/Etc

Tags: standards, web-applications, resources, mobile-website, wap

New to WAP, are there any good resources out there for WAP on Smart phones IE: Android/iPhone/WebOS/Etc...

Looking to do some dev work but don't know where to get started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern smartphones don't use WAP... just standard HTML/Javascript.  There are many tutorials on the web for this... just to give a couple of examples:

- http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/iphone.html
- http://building-iphone-apps.labs.oreilly.com/

Comment: understandable but I would like to use WAP for this project.

Comment: @Phill - That's nice, but WML is not supported on iPhone/Android.

Comment: @Phil - I'm curious, why do you want to use WAP? If you are new to it, there is little point in starting to learn it as it has long since been superseded.

Comment: @Kevin it's more for demo purpose and wanted to grasp the concept of real world uses/practices

Comment: @Phil - there aren't any real world uses of WAP on smartphones. You need to either get your hands on an old phone and do WAP on that. Or, better yet, look at mobile HTML for smartphones - do the latter and you'll be learning something useful.

Comment: I understand WAP is a Older technology, but sometimes we can find new uses today for old technology. Just looking for some info, anyone???